# How to determine which Python class provides attributes when inheriting

Tags: python, inheritance

What's the easiest way to determine which Python class defines an attribute when inheriting? For example, say I have:

```
class A(object):

    defined_in_A = 123

class B(A):
    pass

a = A()
b = B()
```

and I wanted this code to pass:

```
assert hasattr(a, 'defined_in_A')
assert hasattr(A, 'defined_in_A')
assert hasattr(b, 'defined_in_A')
assert hasattr(B, 'defined_in_A')

assert defines_attribute(A, 'defined_in_A')
assert not defines_attribute(B, 'defined_in_A')
```

How would I implement the fictional `defines_attribute` function? My first thought would be to walk through the entire inheritance chain, and use `hasattr` to check for the attribute's existence, with the deepest match assumed to be the definer. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: What's the actual use case for this?

Comment: `if 'defined_in_A' not in vars(B)` would probably be what you are looking for, checking only the instance variables defined on that object without checking it's bases or type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Almost) Every python object is defined with it's own instance variables (instance variables of a class object we usually call class variables) to get this as a dictionary you can use the [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=built#vars) function and check for membership in it:

```
>>> "defined_in_A" in vars(A)
True
>>> "defined_in_A" in vars(B)
False
>>> "defined_in_A" in vars(a) or "defined_in_A" in vars(b)
False
```

the issue with this is that it does not work when a class uses `__slots__` or builtin objects since it changes how the instance variables are stored:

```
class A(object):
    __slots__ = ("x","y")
    defined_in_A = 123

>>> A.x
<member 'x' of 'A' objects>
>>> "x" in vars(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    "x" in vars(a)
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
>>> vars(1) #or floats or strings will raise the same error
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

I'm not sure there is a simple workaround for this case.